# How to list all packages in android project?

Tags: android

I downloaded google's sample in app purchase app and renamed the package to "com.iap.android.trivialdrivesample" wherever it appeared in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iap.android.trivialdrivesample"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <!-- VERY IMPORTANT! Don't forget this permission, or in-app billing won't work. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.iap.android.trivialdrivesample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Uploading the apk into google play shows the error "cannot use package name com.example".  I expanded all my folders in android studio and don't see any packages starting with "com.example".  How can I list them from the command line to make sure?

Comment: Check the package line in all your java files.  It should match your folder layout

Comment: Also, don't upload trivial examples to Google Play.  Just sideload them as needed.  All you do is make it harder to find decent apps.  There's no development reason to do this.